# Using work manager to download data when app is removed from foreground

Tags: android, android-workmanager

What I am doing :

- I need to download a file of 100 mb from background
- I am using work manager with retrofit to achieve this
- I am launching retrofit from work manager
- It is a one time download (once I download the file. I don't need the service running in background to download again)

What is Happening :

- If I keep the app in the foreground I am successfully able to
  download the file
- But say once after launching the worker thread I close the app. I
  notice file don't get download in background.

**Question**: How to make sure all 100 mb file is downloaded in background till completion

---

**In activity I am launching:**

```
 final WorkManager mWorkManager = WorkManager.getInstance(context);
            final OneTimeWorkRequest mRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(DictionaryWorker.class)
                    .setConstraints(new Constraints.Builder()
                            .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                            .setRequiresBatteryNotLow(true)
                            .setRequiresStorageNotLow(true)
                            .build())
                    .addTag(DICTIONARY_WORKER_TAG)
                    .build();
            mWorkManager.enqueue(mRequest);
```

**In the worker class:**

```
public class DictionaryWorker extends Worker {

    private final String CURRENT_SCREEN =  DictionaryWorker.this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    private static final String WORK_RESULT = "work_result";


    private Context context;
    private NetworkComponent networkComponent;


    public DictionaryWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        initCnxNetworkConnection(context);
        Data outputData = new Data.Builder().putString(WORK_RESULT, "Jobs Finished").build();
        return Result.failure(outputData);

    }

    private RandomUsersApi getNetworkService(Context context) {
        if(networkComponent==null){
            networkComponent = DaggerNetworkComponent.builder()
                    .contextModule(new ContextModule(context))
                    .networkModule(new NetworkModule())
                    .okHttpClientModule(new OkHttpClientModule())
                    .build();

        }
        return networkComponent.getService();
    }


    /********************************************************** RETROFIT *************************************************/
    private void initCnxNetworkConnection(final Context context) {

        try{
            Call<ResponseBody> call = getNetworkService(context).downloadDictionary();
            call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                   //File is downloaded here and written to storage
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                    Timber.e(CURRENT_SCREEN, "error");
                }
            });
        }catch (Exception ex){
            incompleteDownload();
            Timber.e(CURRENT_SCREEN, "error%s", ex);
        }


    }
    /********************************************************** RETROFIT *************************************************/


}
```

### I am just trying for below scenario

```
Guaranteed execution:– The WorkManager will make sure to start the execution of background tasks under different conditions, even if we come out of the app.
```